# Chrono-like clock with different epoch (from 1.1. 2000)

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime

The following will by my simple helper, that should behave just like [`std::chrono::system_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) but with the epoch being 1.1. 2000, that I can easily cast durations to seconds (or milliseconds or centiseconds) and store them in some records (originated from small devices).

It all started with one `constexpr`:

```
/// 1.1.2000 0:00
    static constexpr time_point<system_clock> epoch
      = time_point<system_clock>(seconds(946681200))
```

Which helped me to get e.g. milliseconds from 1.1.2000 like this:

```
duration_cast<milliseconds>( system_clock::now() - epoch ).count()
```

The problem is, that there is no contract / specification what is the epoch, but usually is 1.1. 1970.

*(I have once selected 1.1. 2000 because of RTCs in units and designed the firmware to work until 1.1. 2100 when I will probably be dead already or very very old man and won't have to care... record size and amount of data transmitted was more important at the time I have designed the protocol.)*

*(There are some `using std::chrono::system_clock` and such inside `namespace firda` in that header)*

```
#include "basics.hpp"
using namespace firda;

/// Clock with altered epoch
template<class Clock = system_clock
  , typename Clock::rep Epoch = 946681200>
  struct adapted_clock {

    using rep        = typename Clock::rep;
    using period     = typename Clock::period;
    using duration   = typename Clock::duration;
    using time_point = typename firda::time_point<adapted_clock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady
      = Clock::is_steady;
    static constexpr typename Clock::time_point epoch
      = typename Clock::time_point(seconds(Epoch));

    static time_point now() {
        return time_point(Clock::now() - epoch);
    }

    static time_t to_time_t(const time_point& t) {
        return Clock::to_time_t(epoch + t.time_since_epoch());
    }

    static time_point from_time_t(time_t t) {
        return time_point(Clock::from_time_t(t) - epoch);
    }
};

using y2k_clock = adapted_clock<>;

int main() {
    auto now1 = system_clock::now();
    auto now2 = y2k_clock::now();
    cout << "now1.count: " << duration_cast<seconds>(now1
      .time_since_epoch()).count() << '\n';
    cout << "now2.count: " << duration_cast<seconds>(now2
      .time_since_epoch()).count() << '\n';
    time_t time1 = system_clock::to_time_t(now1);
    time_t time2 = y2k_clock::to_time_t(now2);
    cout << "time1: " << std::ctime(&time1) << '\n';
    cout << "time2: " << std::ctime(&time2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: 946681200s past Jan/1/1970 00:00:00 is Dec/31/1999 23:00:00. Did you mean 946684800s?

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Yes, I have probably mixed it badly with local time (CET ~ GMT+1). 946681200/3600=262967 which is odd. 946684800/3600/24=10957=30*365+7 (30*365.25 = 10957.5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frankly, there isn't much to say about this class since it is simple enough *and* relies on another simple clock. The type alias, static members and static methods seem to all rely just like they should on the template parameter `Clock` so there is no problem. I believe that `firda::time_point` is nothing really from `std::chrono::time_point` os this shouldn't be a problem either.

The only remarks I have is about the template parameters: I am not sure whether defaulting `Clock` to `std::chrono::system_clock` makes sense. Is it really the *default* clock amongst the three standard clocks? If you think so, why. But frankly, defaulting `Epoch` has no sense: `adapted_clock<>` doesn't tell anything about the epoch to the user and you already provide the meaningful type alias `y2k_clock` (note that using the defaults is *always* equivalent to using `y2k_clock`, which makes them useless). You can't default `Clock` without defaulting `Epoch` though because you can't change the order of the template parameters.

I think that the best solution would be to leave undefaulted template parameters in `adapted_clock` but make `y2l_clock` an alias template with a possibly default `Clock` template parameter:

```
template<typename Clock=std::chrono::system_clock>
using y2k_clock = adapted_clock<Clock, 946681200>;
```

If you don't like this alias template solution, I would still recommend not to default the template parameters of `adapted_clock` but instead to write this:

```
using y2k_clock = adapted_clock<std::chrono::system_clock, 946681200>;
```

Comment: I will take your hints into consideration. `firda::time_point = std::time_point` if selected in the header (which is by default). I use it to be able to swith to boost or any other implementation as needed. The design and defaulted template params are towards the goal - the y2k_clock (year 2000 clock) and adapted_clock thus prefer this epoch (and allow other clocks to be used). But I take it that I should think from the opposite side: who and how will use that ;) Making another template specifically adjusting to Y2K sounds good.